# Abel's limit theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following statement :
For a power series $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} a_n x^n$, with radius of convergence 1,
$\sum a_n = \infty$ implies $lim _{x \to 1- } f(x) = \infty$.

My attempt:

Set a real positve number $r$.  There exists a natural number $N$ s.t. for all $m\geq N$ , $\sum_0 ^ma_n$ is greater than $r$. From this I want to get the inequality $\sum a_n y^n > r $ for $y$ sufficiently close to 1 from below, but I'm stuck here. Whenever I try to get an estimation, there is always $N$ in the estimation and cannot get rid of it. For example $\sum a_n y^n = \sum_{n=0} ^{N-1} a_n y^n + \sum_{n>=N} a_n y^n > \sum_{n=0} ^{N-1} a_n y^n + r y^N$

by Abel's lemma , but N depends on r.

Can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right start using the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^m a_n\geq r$ for all $m\geq N$. There is nothing wrong with using the resulting $N$. One approach from there would be to split $a_n$ into a "head" and "tail" $b_n$ and $c_n$ such that

- $a_n=b_n+c_n$ for all $n$
- $b_n=0$ for $n>N$
- $c_n=0$ for $n<N$
- $\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n=r$
- $\sum_{n=0}^m c_n\geq 0$ for all $m\geq 0$

from which the rest should be quite easy.

(It is a little fiddly to get $\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n=r$ exactly - the argument could be simplified a little by picking $r$ such that $r=\min_{M\geq N} \sum_{n=0}^M a_n$, i.e. a value $r=\sum_{n=0}^M a_n$ such that all subsequent sums are greater than or equal to $r$.)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.